# Access first item of array using async pipe in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

How to access the first item of an array when using async pipe?

```
<nav-tabs
   [tabs]="(pageTabs$ | async)"
   [activeTab]="(pageTabs$ | async)[0]">
</nav-tabs>
```

I've tried `(pageTabs$ | async)[0]` but it didn't work.

Comment: Actually, this is how it is done. But actually, this smells, because pageTabs$ is subscribed twice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found an even easier way of doing it (without creating a custom pipe): add a map to the observable.

**component.ts**

```
this.activeTab$ = this.pageTabs$.map(x => x[0]);
```

**component.html**

```
<nav-tabs
   [tabs]="(pageTabs$ | async)"
   [activeTab]="(activeTab$ | async)">
</nav-tabs>
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way it's to assign it to a template value with the `as` statement

```
<nav-tabs
   [tabs]="(pageTabs$ | async as pageTabs)"
   [activeTab]="pageTabs[0]">
</nav-tabs>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just write a new getter in your components code:

```
 public get activeTab$() {
   return this.pageTabs$.map(tabs => Array.isArray(tabs)? tabs[0]: null;
 }
```

and then use it:

```
 [active-tab]="activeTab$ | async"
```

Or you can do it in your nav-tabs component:

```
 public get activeTab() {
    return Array.isArray(this.tabs)? tabs[0]: null;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom pipe which will take first item from array, `(pageTabs$ | async)` is not an array.